# Jwt token Errorcode IDX12709

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, jwt

I generate a jwt token and after I try to Read it again, i get followed error message:
*IDX12709: CanReadToken() returned false. JWT is not well formed: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden*

GenerateToken:

```
private string GenerateJwtToken(string username)
{
   var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
   var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("$x3H*aG*?yKfh]Z/");
   var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
   {
      Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("username", username) }),
      Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),
      SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
   };
   var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
   return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

and the Fetch Header:

```
headers: {
   'Content-type': 'application/json',
   'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("token")}`,
},
```

Here I read the token: *"(backslash)"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImRldl9lZCIsIm5iZiI6MTY0MzQwMTc2OSwiZXhwIjoxNjQzNDAzNTY5LCJpYXQiOjE2NDM0MDE3Njl9.EjE9Va6v7XwQka4UH0y_2dC1eqpfUWAGs2Ipoq9LoGE(backslash)""*

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthService authService)
{
   string token = string token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();
//...

private void attachUserToContext(HttpContext context, IAuthService authService, string token)
{
   try
   {
      var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
      var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("$x3H*aG*?yKfh]Z/");
      tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters //<- IDX12709
      {
         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
         IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
         ValidateIssuer = false,
         ValidateAudience = false,
         ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
      }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
      var jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)validatedToken;
      var userId = int.Parse(jwtToken.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "username").Value);
      context.Items["User"] = userId;
      }
      catch
      {
         // do nothing if jwt validation fails
         // user is not attached to context so request won't have access to secure routes
      }
}
```

Comment: is it literally like you wrote *"Bearer "eyJhbG...""* (token in "" behind Bearer)? Then these extra "" are probably the problem.

Comment: @jps now the token looks like that *"\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImRldl9lZCIsIm5iZiI6MTY0MzQwMTc2OSwiZXhwIjoxNjQzNDAzNTY5LCJpYXQiOjE2NDM0MDE3Njl9.EjE9Va6v7XwQka4UH0y_2dC1eqpfUWAGs2Ipoq9LoGE\""* and is still not valid

Comment: There should be no "" at all. The header should be `Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIU...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like @jps said, it was because of the quotation mark.

new fetch call:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.replace(/"/g, ""),
```